# initializeError while Unit-testing Mock objects with Mockito in Xtend

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, initialization, mockito, xtend

I'm trying to run this unit test, I'm currently using Xtend over Java in order to read the code easily.
The test consist on an admin who must verify a user in order to add it or not to the current repository. I want to make that admin a mock object in order to verify if the user has send correctly the method "generateProfile", which do the following

```js
class User{
  @Accessors
  repositoryAdministrator admin
  
  def generateProfile{
    admin.add(this)
  }
```

the method add is the following:

```js
class repositoryAdministrator{
  @Accessors List<User> objects
  @Accessors List<User> usersToValidate
  
  def add(User user){
    usersToValidate.add(user)
    }
```

This is the test i want to run using the lib Mockito

```js
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner)
class MockitoTests{

val lala = new User()  
  
@Mock
repositoryAdministrator fakeAdmin

@Before
def void init(){
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
  }

@Test
def validationTest(){
   
 lala.admin = fakeAdmin
 lala.generateProfile
  
 Mockito.verify(fakeAdmin).add(lala)
  }
}
```

I have imported correctly the libraries, I'm working on an Eclipse IDE, and when i run the test I keep on getting initializationError.

How do I properly initialize a mock object using Mockito? Sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

I've already found the problem, test using Xtend are not necessary to define the return type... Until you implement Mockito dependencies on a Maven proyect. There was a problem in the add method of the admin, it return a bool variable and it should return void, the way to fix it was:

```js
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner)
class MockitoTests{

val lala = new User()  
  
@Mock
repositoryAdministrator fakeAdmin

@Before
def void init(){
 MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
  }

@Test
def void validationTest(){
   
 lala.admin = fakeAdmin
 lala.generateProfile
  
 Mockito.verify(fakeAdmin).add(lala)
  }
}
```

I only define the return type in the test, which should be in this case **void**